# Find product defects in a photograph

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt

I have been trying to find defects (brown/copper parts) on this sample using PyQt, OpenCV and Python:

[image: Sample with copper parts]

And I can find defects, too. My problem is, I have nobody to ask, get feedback etc. I need some feedback about my code. Of course, I don't want someone to review my code line-by-line, but even a simple reviewing would be good, because I am very new to Python. I will using this on laptop

### `view.ui` [file](https://easyupload.io/jb0maw)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="windowModality">
   <enum>Qt::NonModal</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>751</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>320</width>
     <height>240</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShape">
    <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="scaledContents">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>420</x>
     <y>90</y>
     <width>70</width>
     <height>100</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShape">
    <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="scaledContents">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="buton2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>340</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Find Defects</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>380</x>
     <y>240</y>
     <width>171</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Size of defects on the lower part</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>380</x>
     <y>280</y>
     <width>161</width>
     <height>80</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="widgetResizable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>159</width>
      <height>78</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>400</x>
     <y>420</y>
     <width>104</width>
     <height>71</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>620</x>
     <y>90</y>
     <width>70</width>
     <height>100</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShape">
    <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="scaledContents">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>580</x>
     <y>240</y>
     <width>171</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Size of defects on the upper part</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>600</x>
     <y>420</y>
     <width>104</width>
     <height>71</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>580</x>
     <y>280</y>
     <width>161</width>
     <height>80</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="widgetResizable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>159</width>
      <height>78</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

### `main.py`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from view import loadUi_example
from model import Camera

if __name__ == '__main__':

    camera = Camera(0)
    app = QApplication([])
    start_window = loadUi_example(camera)
    start_window.show()
    app.exit(app.exec_())
```

### `view.py`

```
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage


class loadUi_example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, cam_num):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi("view.ui", self)
        self.cam_num = cam_num
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.textEdit) #size of defects will be shown in scrollArea
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidget(self.textEdit_2)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.readNextFrame)
        self.timer.start(1000 / 24) #24 fps

    def readNextFrame(self):
        self.frame = self.cam_num.read()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_buton2_clicked(self):
        if self.frame is not None:
            image = QImage(self.frame, self.frame.shape[1], self.frame.shape[0],
                           QImage.Format_RGB888)  # The image is stored using a 24-bit RGB format (8-8-8).
            self.pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        lower_sample,upper_sample = self.cam_num.find_sample()

        lowerPartDefects,the_list = self.cam_num.find_defects(lower_sample)

        qImg = self.fit_image(lowerPartDefects)
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImg))

        self.list_defects(the_list)
        self.textEdit.setText(self.line)

        upperPartDefects, the_list = self.cam_num.find_defects(upper_sample)

        qImg = self.fit_image(upperPartDefects)
        self.label_3.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImg))

        self.list_defects(the_list)
        self.textEdit_2.setText(self.line)

    def list_defects(self,the_list):
        self.line = ""
        i = 1
        for x in the_list:
            self.line += "Size of defect %d = %d\n" % (i, x)
            i = i + 1
        return self.line

    def fit_image(self,image):
        h, w, ch = image.shape
        bytesPerLine = ch * w
        qImg = QtGui.QImage(image.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        return qImg
```

### `model.py`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


class Camera:

    def __init__(self, cam_num):
        self.cap = None

    def read(self):
        self.frame = cv2.imread('input.png')
        self.frame = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        return self.frame

    def find_sample(self):
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
        lower_limit = np.array([0, 0, 93])
        upper_limit = np.array([255, 255, 255])
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_limit, upper_limit)  #created a mask to remove background
        mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
        bg = cv2.bitwise_and(self.frame, self.frame, mask=mask)
        fg = cv2.bitwise_and(self.frame, self.frame, mask=mask_inv)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(bg,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1] #findContours function works better with binary images
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 11))
        thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel) #remove noise
        thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
        cntrs = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1] #It accounts for the fact that different versions of OpenCV return different number of values for findContours().
        area_thresh = 5000
        cnt = 0
        for c in cntrs:
            area = cv2.contourArea(c)
            if area > area_thresh:
                cnt= cnt + 1
            if cnt > 0:
                rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c) #minArearect returns - ( center (x,y), (width, height), angle of rotation ).
                box = cv2.boxPoints(rect) # The function finds the four vertices of a rotated rectangle.
                box = np.int0(box) #converting numbers to integer
                # crop image inside bounding box
                centerX = rect[0][0]
                centerY = rect[0][1]
                W = rect[1][0] #width of contour
                H = rect[1][1] #height of contour
                Xs = [i[0] for i in box]
                Ys = [i[1] for i in box]
                x1 = min(Xs)
                x2 = max(Xs)
                y1 = min(Ys)
                y2 = max(Ys)
                angle = rect[2]
                rotated = False
                if angle < -45:
                    angle += 90
                    rotated = True
                center = (round(centerX), round(centerY))
                size = (int((x2 - x1)), int( (y2 - y1)))
                M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((size[0] / 2, size[1] / 2), angle, 1.0)
                #Calculates an affine matrix of 2D rotation.
                cropped = cv2.getRectSubPix(self.frame, size, center) #crop contour
                cropped = cv2.warpAffine(cropped, M, size) #rotate contour using 2D-RotationMatrix
                croppedW = W if not rotated else H
                croppedH = H if not rotated else W
                self.image = cv2.getRectSubPix(
                    cropped, (int(croppedW ), int(croppedH )), (size[0] / 2, size[1] / 2)) #crop contour
                if croppedH > croppedW:
                    if cnt == 1:
                        output1 = self.image[0:self.image.shape[0] - 70, 0: self.image.shape[1]]
                    if cnt == 2:  # bitis
                        output2 = self.image[70:self.image.shape[0] , 0: self.image.shape[1]]
        return output1,output2

    def find_defects (self, sample):
        self.the_list = []
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(sample,
                            cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        mask = cv2.inRange(gray, 4, 43)
        bg = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask=mask)
        thresh = cv2.threshold(bg, 4, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1] #remove non-defect parts
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
        thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
        thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
        cntrs = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        # APPROX_SIMPLE compresses horizontal, vertical, and diagonal segments and leaves only their end points.
        # For example, an up-right rectangular contour is encoded with 4 points.
        cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]
        for c in cntrs:
            area = cv2.contourArea(c)
            area_thresh = 500
            if area > area_thresh:
                x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                cv2.rectangle(sample, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (200, 0, 0), 2)
                self.the_list.append(area)
        return sample, self.the_list

    def close_camera(self):
        self.cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: That's not quite complete - I think you need the `view.ui` file for anybody to test the program.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I've added the contents of the file to your question. For context, will you be running this on a laptop, PC, server or an embedded platform (like Raspberry)? OpenCV handles just a bit different on different platforms and this may be relevant for the resource usage as well.